# One Android MediaPlayer Object plays several sounds at once

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have ONE object MediaPlayer mediaplayer. I use it to play different sounds, one after another.

```
mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, ResIdMusicONE);
mediaplayer.start();

// some user input

mediaplayer.release();
mediaplayer = null;

// some other user input

mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, ResIdMusicTWO);
mediaplayer.start();

// some user input

mediaplayer.release();
mediaplayer = null;
```

Sometimes is works fine. But sometimes the two sounds are played at the same time. And at positions, where mediaplayer should already have been released and be equal null.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use the SoundPool class for this. With SoundPool you can set the number of streams to play at the same time, so by setting that to 1 you can just call play() over and over and the most recent call to play() will be the only sound that you hear.

Take a look at [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957444/playing-sounds-simultaneously-android) a while back. It has an example of the SoundPool class in the question.

**Edit:**
Have you tried creating a new instance and calling the prepare() every time you want to start a new sound?

```
mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaplayer.setDataSource(path);
mediaplayer.prepare();
mediaplayer.start();
```

Though actually now that I think about it, I'm pretty sure you only need to do that if you are using a file from the sdcard not from your resources... Hmmm.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. i first used soundpool and i still do for some short, often used sounds. but for the music-files, sound pool didn't well work (maybe there was a memory problem). the files i want to play have 30 - 60kb in ogg format.

Comment: Yea SoundPool isn't really meant for playing longer sounds, I had issues with that as well. I edited my answer with a suggestion, have you tried that?

Comment: i tried that. still occurs the same problems. sometimes, now it simply doesn't play at all. i also tried with `mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener ... start()`. But then the problem becomes the same as all above.