# how to make two buttons play sound together

Tags: android

When I touch sound play sound but when I touch another it stop play this sound. I need to sound don't stop playing.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(1);

    }
});       
        Button SoundButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
        SoundButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(2);

    }
});    
        Button SoundButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound3);
        SoundButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`enter code here`

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in my comment shows that you have initialized your sound pool with 1 as the value for maxStreams. If you set this value to the maximum amount of sounds you want to be able to play at the same time, it should work.

You have `mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);`

If you change that to `mSoundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);`
You will be able to play 5 sounds at once.

I'd need to take a look at your sound manager class to have a better idea of what is wrong with it. However, it is perfectly possible.

Take a look at this:
[Playing sounds simultaneously Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957444/playing-sounds-simultaneously-android)

Comment: public class SoundManager {
 
 private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
 private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
 private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
 private  Context mContext;
 
 
 public SoundManager()
 {
  
 }
  
 @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
 public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
   mContext = theContext;
      mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
      mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
      mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);       
 } 
 
 public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)